# php - opendir, force listing hidden files (ftp)

Tags: php, list, ftp, opendir

How to force listing hidden files with ftp connection in PHP script? Is there any context option for opendir?

Thanks

Comment: RTM: [PHP has some functions for FTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php)

Comment: And no one has option to force listing hidden files...

Answer (score 4):

"ftp_rawlist — Returns a detailed list of files in the given directory" (raw => ALL incl. hidden)

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php

---

There is one [comment to the `ftp_rawlist`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#97876):

> Get a listing of all files including hidden files except '.' or '..' use:
>
> ```
> <?php
> ftp_chdir($connid, $dir);
> ftp_rawlist($connid, "-A");
> ?>
> ```
>
> This had me dancing in circles for some time!

Comment: I tried all these ftp functions, but neither ftp_rawlist listed hidden files... When I connect to ftp server with e.g. FileZilla, I see it.

Comment: Yes, I did not notice that... ftp_rawlist($link, "-A /"); works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: +1 - Though, the `-A` is a non-standard feature, supported by **some** FTP servers, like [proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_ListOptions.html). It won't work on all FTP servers. It's particularly not supported by another widespread FTP server, the vsftpd. Both proftpd and vsftpd support lowercase `-a` (which will list `.` and `..` in additional to all files). - FileZila FTP server lists hidden files always, and silently ignores `-a` and `-A` switches. - Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34231045/850848 for an exactly opposite question.

Comment: I had no choice but to use `-A` to get .htaccess to copy, and since this is a flag, it must come **first** if including a path. So followed by a space and the path, like: (no new lines in Stackoverflow comments)  `ftp_rawlist($connid, '-A '.$remote_path);`