# Why is ftp_nlist returning an empty array for a non-empty directory?

Tags: php, ftp

The following line in my code is returning an empty array when in fact the given path is not empty:

```
$file_list = @ftp_nlist( $link, '-a ' . $path );
```

The permission on the path is 775.  When I `ls` the path in my OS shell, I see the expected list of files.

So why isn't `ftp_nlist` seeing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely because the FTP server does not understand the `-a`. It tries to interpret it as a path or a file mask. It matches no file, hence the empty result set.

Try to remove the switch.

---

Note that while some servers do support the `-a`, or are at least able to ignore it, it violates the FTP specification. There are no switches at all in `NLST` command (or any other FTP command).